# How to get a \widetilde with FiraMath?

Tags: math-mode, mathtools, fira-sans

It seems that widetilde is not available with FiraMath.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\usepackage{firamath-otf}

\begin{document}

$\widetilde{G_{+, 0}}$

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to fake it? (I'm using `lualatex`).

Comment: Complaining with the font developers?

Comment: @egreg I could... But they've done an amazing job with this font. Let's go instead for a big thank you to the developers and a search for a way to fake it `;-)`.

Comment: I'm afraid that math accents with `unicode-math` are quite hard to handle.

Comment: @egeg Ah. Too bad. Would you have some time to elaborate on the "quite hard to handle" part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to replace the accent with one from another font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{firamath-otf}

\newfontface{\dvmath}{texgyredejavu-math.otf}[
  NFSSFamily=dvm,
  Script=Math,% <---- important!
]
\DeclareSymbolFont{dvm}{TU}{dvm}{m}{n}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\widehat}{\Umathaccent 7 \symdvm "00302\relax}%
  \renewcommand{\widetilde}{\Umathaccent 7 \symdvm "00303\relax}%
}

\begin{document}

$\widetilde{G_{+, 0}} \widehat{abc}$

\end{document}
```

#### Output with XeLaTeX

[image]

#### Output with LuaLaTeX

[image]

Thanks to Marcel Krüger for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: sir, as usual, excellent reply.

Comment: Thanks (+1). And could you explain why lualatex is different here?

Comment: @cjorssen No, sorry. It *should* work.

Comment: Ok. But is it an engine issue, a font issue, a `fontspec` / `luaotfload` issue or a `unicode-math` issue?

Comment: @cjorssen Waiting for experts to chime in.

Comment: @egreg You need to add `Script=Math` to the fontspec call to get proper math handling in LuaTeX.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Good point! Thanks!

Comment: @cjorssen Marcel suggested the magic incantation!

Comment: @MarcelKrüger In which package documentation could I have found this trick?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, the below meets the expectation, but some how :-D

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\usepackage[]{firamath-otf}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}

$\stackon[0pt]{G_{+, 0}}{\hstretch{4}{\sim}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks (+1). That's a quick hack that will do the job.